# Adding circle polygon to folium map (using OGR and Python) creates an oval - why?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, ogr, folium

I am new to OGR and Folium but learning fast. In short, I have an issue which I think might be a projection problem.

Basically, I have three circles plotted in folium that work fine. Then I have a fourth circle that I created with OGR, by adding a point then buffering it and plotting the geoJSON polygone onto the folium map. This fourth circle comes out as an oval, see:

[image]

The code to make this is as follows:

```
import folium
import pandas as pd
import json
from numpy import median
from osgeo import ogr

# MY CO-ORDINATES -- FOUR POINTS

datatest = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

p1_lat, p1_lon, p2_lat, p2_lon, p3_lat, p3_lon, p4_lat, p4_lon = datatest['POINT1_LAT'], datatest['POINT1_LON'], datatest['POINT2_LAT'], datatest['POINT2_LON'], datatest['POINT3_LAT'], datatest['POINT3_LON'], datatest['POINT4_LAT'], datatest['POINT4_LON']

# CENTER THE MAP

middle_lat = median([p1_lat, p2_lat, p3_lat, p4_lat])
middle_lon = median([p1_lon, p2_lon, p3_lon, p4_lon])

testmap = folium.Map(location=[middle_lat, middle_lon], zoom_start=13)

# MAKE THREE FOLIUM CIRCULES

folium.Circle(location=[p1_lat, p1_lon], popup='Point 1A', fill_color='#000', radius=2000, weight=2, color="#000").add_to(testmap)
folium.Circle(location=[p2_lat, p2_lon], popup='Point 1B', fill_color='#000', radius=2000, weight=2, color="#000").add_to(testmap)
folium.Circle(location=[p3_lat, p3_lon], popup='Point 1C', fill_color='#008080', radius=1000, weight=2, color="#008080").add_to(testmap)

# MAKE A FOURTH CIRCULE IN OGR

p4_lat = float(p4_lat[0])
p4_lon = float(p4_lon[0])

point_four = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point_four.AddPoint(p4_lon, p4_lat)

bufferDistance = 0.01
poly = point_four.Buffer(bufferDistance)

geojson_poly = poly.ExportToJson()

# STYLING THE FOURTH CIRCLE (IGNORE THIS)

import random

def random_html_color():
    r = random.randint(0,256)
    g = random.randint(0,256)
    b = random.randint(0,256)
    return '#%02x%02x%02x' % (r, g, b)

def style_fcn(x):
    return { 'fillColor': random_html_color() }

def highlight_fcn(x):
    return { 'fillColor': '#ff0000' }

# ADD CIRCLE FOUR TO FOLIUM

folium.GeoJson(geojson_poly,name='geojson', style_function=style_fcn).add_to(testmap)

# GENERATE MAP SEEN IN IMAGE

testmap.save('testing_map.html')
```

So, can anyone tell me why my OGR point is an oval shape? Do I need to set the proper projection somewhere? Presumably to WGS 1984?

EDIT: CSV coordinates are (1-4 in rows, lat and lon):

```
40.729047,-73.957472
40.70797,-73.93095
40.706799,-73.958416
40.681289,-74.004936
```

Comment: Could you please also provide the coordinates that are in the `*.csv` file?

Comment: Have provided csv coordinates as req

Answer (score 1):

Your buffer:

```py
bufferDistance = 0.01
poly = point_four.Buffer(bufferDistance)
```

is applied to the Lat/Long point, so the value `0.01` is in units of degrees.

With the method `folium.Circle` the [radius](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.vector_layers.Circle) parameter is in units of meters.

Perhaps the simplest fix is to use `folium.Circle` to plot the forth circle as well.

It is a bit messier, but you could also reproject your points into a flat projection (maybe [epsg:6347](https://epsg.io/6347),) apply the buffer, and then plot.

Edit: Using [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/) for the second option (Warning, didn't actually run this code)

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'lat':[p1_lat, p2_lat, p3_lat, p4_lat],
        'lon':[p1_lon, p2_lon, p3_lon, p4_lon],
        'rad':[2000, 2000, 1000, 100]
    }
)
df['geom'] = df.apply(lambda r: Point(r['lon'], r['lat']), axis=1)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geom', crs='epsg:4326')
gdf_flat = gdf.to_crs('epsg:6347')
gdf_flat['geom'] = gdf_flat.geometry.buffer(df.rad)
gdf = gdf_flat.to_crs('epsg:4326')
gdf.to_file('data.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
```

Comment: Hi -- thanks! That makes lots more sense. However, I'd like to plot it all in OGR because I may not end up using folium for this project. Is there a way to create the circle with OGR (or sth else) *before* it is plotted into folium (or anything else)? I'd like to get all my geometry done in geoJSON ideally before it goes to be plotted anywhere (by anything!).

Comment: I've never done this with plain OGR calls, but I did update the answer with how to do it with GeoPandas.

Comment: Mhmmm, code gives me an error on the last line with Invalid field type...

Comment: It works for me, perhaps you added a field that isn't supported by JSON? Maybe a Datetime object?

Comment: Ovals, or, more accurately, egg shapes, are expected when buffering in degrees. Plotting them in Web Mercator warps them differently, as well.

Comment: Hi @Vince -- well, ideally I'd like to buffer in metres... I just want a way to create a simple circle that I can plot with WGS84 and Folium.

Comment: A simple circle in WGS84 degrees doesn't *look* like a circle.  You need to choose to either accept the correct geometry, or force incorrect rendering.

Comment: Thanks good point, but I guess as I said I'd like it to be like the folium circles shown next to it...